# Kuraz vs Trap hole, still draw?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

Player A summons Kuraz, selects 1 set card to destroy on player B's field, player B chains by activating the set card which is Trap Hole, Kuraz is destroyed, but ..

Will Trap Hole is considered "destroyed" so player B draw a card? Or it's sent to graveyard by resolving so player B doesn't draw card?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good read over here: [Chains, Activation, and Resolution](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Chains,_Activation,_and_Resolution)

> IMPORTANT: When resolving a chain, as the cards resolve they are NOT sent to the Graveyard until the entire chain has resolved, or a card specifically destroys them

So in this case, since Trap Hole is on a same chain with Kuraz, Trap Hole is destroyed by Kuraz, and the controller of Trap Hole is allowed to draw a card.